# Joining 2 tables with foreign key id

Tags: php, mysql

i have a 2 category system, basically what i want to do is i have 2 tables, top_category and bottom_category, i have created my sidebar which will list all the products using sql query. is there a way i can pull the top_category and bottom_category data in one sql query and have the bottom_category sorted by the foreign key id of top_category so when i loop them in a list they end up in the right nest?

Here are my tables,

```
CREATE TABLE top_category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) 
);

CREATE TABLE bottom_category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) ,
  top_category_id INT REFERENCES top_category
);
```

And here is my products table, so when i click on a bottom_category link i want it to list the products linked to the bottom_category_id's:

```
create table product (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(100) ,
  bottom_category_id int references bottom_category
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like

```
SELECT product.*, bottom_category.name, top_category.name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN bottom_category ON bottom_category.id = product.bottom_category_id 
LEFT JOIN top_category ON top_category.id = bottom_category.top_category_id
ORDER BY top_category.id,bottom_category.id
```

But if you have really big tables then just forget about 3nd normal form and add names for categories into product table. But *only* if you have really big tables with categories.

**UPD**
Add `ORDER BY`

Comment: basically i have top category of about 30 categories, then sub categories are about 50-100, and then about 12k products. also i will need to be able to have a backend that can CRUD this navigation.

Comment: Then there would be no problem with SQL above.
Also for your information:

If you would change `LEFT` to `INNER` then you would find only products that have bottom and top categories. In `LEFT` case you _could_ find `NULL` in `bottom_category.name` and `top_category.name`

Comment: this is not displaying anything, but the query works, which data from the pdo query do i echo out?

Comment: what column do i echo out? because i am echoing out the top and bottom category names, and because i have multiple products linking back to one category, my foreach loop is looping through the same category and making duplicate top and bottom categories until there is no more products in that category?

Comment: You need echo `bottom_category.name` or anything from `product`.
If you need to set specific name for `bottom_category.name` use

`bottom_category.name AS bottom_name` instead if `bottom_category.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*,
      bc.name bc_name,
      tc.name tc_name
from product p
left join bottom_category bc on p.bottom_category_id=bc.id
left join top_category tc on bc.top_category_id=tc.id
order by tc.id,bc.id
```